# Insert image at top of UITableView when using UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have a UINavigationController and UITableView in my MainWindow.xib. I'm trying to insert a non-touchable/non-movable image at the top of the view. (I don't want to simply change the UINavigationBar background, as from what I've experienced, the UINavigationBar height cannot be arbitrarily increased.)

As this is a root view, its behaviour is controlled by my RootViewController. When the view loads, I hide the navigation bar using `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`

I've tried adding a UIView to the top of the UITableView, but when the user scrolls through the table, the top image moves. How can I place a stationary image at the top of the UITableView without it moving as if it were a cell and without using a UINavigationBar background image?

**Naively-Considered Possibilities:**

- Enclose the view in another view, the top of which contains the image?
- Overlay an image mask at the top of the screen?

(HIG violation, anyone?)

Answer (score 1):

You can create another `UIViewController` which contains the `UITableViewController` and your static image on top. This way, you can even resize the table view so the static image is displayed above and not over your table.

```
UIViewController *middleViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[[middleViewController view] addSubview:tableView];
[[middleViewController view] addSubview:staticImageView];
...
[navigationController initWithRootViewController:middleViewController];
```

Has been a long time since I made my last cocoa application, so I cannot promise that it works.

Comment: I think you mean [[middleViewController view] addSubview:tableView];

Answer (score 1):

If your view controller is a `UITableViewController` you can't easily add another view because the tableViewController just manages a single view which is the `UITableView`. I recommend using a plain `UIViewController` instead where you add a `UIView` for your top view and a `UITableView` for your content as subviews to the main `viewController.view`. Then, implement the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols in your `UIViewController`.

Comment: I originally went down a similar path, but thought the navigation controller would help me manage my app's hierarchy and would allow for the handy back arrow as well (which is not allowed in the UIToolBar). I'm not convinced that the navigation controller has helped much.

Comment: You can embed a `UIViewController` with your two subviews in a `UINavigationController` in a `UITabBarController`. That way you get the best of all worlds. Customizing the background of the navigationBar is possible by overwriting `-drawRect:`. However, if you plan to also customize the look of the back button, be prepared to a house of pain.